# Smart way to recompile create-react-app when a dependency changes

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

I’m using create-react-app with inside a package (my-package) that i developed.
My-package is bundled with webpack.

During heavy duty test loops i often change my-package and i re-install it locally in the react-app with `npm i —save ../my-package`, unfortunately this operation is slow and does not trigger a recompile action by the react-app when i’m in `npm start` mode.

It would be nice if i could set `webpack —watch` in my-package and somehow have the bundle served to the react-app + a recompile trigger.

Is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I will split my answer in two parts: how to setup a locally linked package through npm and how to setup create-react-app's Webpack to trigger a recompile.

### Setting up a local package

To setup a local package, you have to create a symlink inside your project's `node_modules` folder pointing to your package. An easy way to do this is with the `npm link` command. To do this, go into your package folder and run `npm link` and then go into your project folder and run `npm link package-name`.

If you did this right, you should be able to check that a symlink was created inside your node_modules folder pointing to your package folder. If it does not work, make sure your `package.json` file points to the right location for your package. e.g:

```
    "dependencies": {
      "package-name": "file:../relative/path/to/your/package"
    }
```

### Making create-react-app trigger a rebuild on local package change

If you look into the source of create-react-app, you will notice that the file `webpackDevServer.config.js` has the following option:

```
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: ignoredFiles(paths.appSrc),
    }
```

Where ignoredFiles is an imports a regex that matches `node_modules`. This means that create-react-app is explicitly ignoring rebuilds on `node_modules` changes (there is an exception though, that is on new package addition, which is done by using `WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin` in `webpack.config.dev.js`).

The reason for this is that some computers are slowed down when checking the whole `node_modules` folder for changes. My suggestion is to override the `ignoredFiles` function, by using a regexp to only exclude your local package. e.g.:

```
    const ignoredFiles = function (appSrc) {
      return new RegExp(
        `^(?!${escape(
          path.normalize(appSrc + '/').replace(/[\\]+/g, '/')
        )}).+/node_modules/(?!package-name)`,
        'g'
      );
    };
```

Unfortunatelly you will have to eject from create-react-app or override your `webpackDevServer.config.js` (by using [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) for example) to be able to apply said changes.

Comment: Beautiful!
I've only one question more: When you say 'Unfortunately you will have to eject from create-react-app OR override your webpackDevServer.config.js' do you mean AND?
For what i see to use rewire you need to access to `const ignoredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/ignoredFiles');` and this line stays in webpackDevServer.config.js that is accessible only if you eject.

Comment: What I mean in that sentence is that you must modify webpackDevServer.config.js, and to do that there are two ways: The easy way is to eject and directly modify the file that will now be in your project folder. The hard way is to change the package.json scripts section to point to a custom startup script that adds some functionality to create-react-app. There is a package that can help you do exactly that: [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired). I personally took the easy way as I was in a rush, but it should definitely be possible to solve it using the hard way too

Comment: This doesn't work for "fast refresh" — the development server does restart correctly with this patch, however the browser does not pick up the change. I assume something else needs to be patched as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that when a dependency is added via the `file:` attribute, CRA will ignore changes.
However, using `link:` instead, CRA starts listening for changes as well.

```
"dependencies": {
  "package-name": "link:../relative/path/to/your/package"
}
```