# How to trigger hot reloading for React when a package in node_modules is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am building a React component library and additional documentation project. My goal is to display immediately all changes of the library straight into the documentation.

So far I have configured webpack to watch for changes in the components. After rebuilding, I take the output folder and move it in the `node_modules` of the documentation. This way I can simulate using my component library as an external package.

The documentation is a `create-react-app` project and by default it does not watch for changes in `node_modules`. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49932996/12575508) and executed the `eject` script. I updated the `ignoredFiles` variable in `webpackDevServer.config.js` and everything is working really fine. I make a change in a component, webpack recompiles, updates the package in the `node_modules` of the docs and then a rebuild is triggered. However, I have to refresh the browser to see the changes. Hot reloading happens when I do a change in the source of the docs, but it will be great to trigger it when I update that specific package in the `node_modules`. Is there a way to achieve that?

Thank you for spending time on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a local dependency that points to your package.

```
"dependencies": {
  "package-name": "file:../relative/path/to/your/package"
}
```

Then, when you created the dependency, rebuild the relative path to the module containing your package.json in watch mode and you are ready to go!

Comment: It works, thanks! In fact, I even refactored the whole setup - since the local dependency in my documentation project is watching the build output and is doing hot reload, there is no need to move code from the library to the `node_modules` of the docs. Way cleaner.

Comment: I just tried this, and because I got no hot reloading I just ended up here. This is not a solution.

Comment: Did you replicate the same procedures?